# Django3: dynamically generating js which I can use in HTML page

Tags: javascript, django

As we know in Django framework we can generate the HTML page based on some predefined template files.
Inside those templates we can use and some specific django keywords/operators/functions.
Like:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{% static 'js/jquery/jquery-ui.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/chosen/chosen.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock stylesheets %}
```

But most important things which I want to touch in this question are related to tag 'translate'

```
"{% trans 'List of all available masters' %}"
```

So I can be sure that the final content of my page will use some predefined language.
And the places where I am using such tags are different: "simple" html content with / and etc tags AND inline javascripts blocks. Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datepicker_value').on('change', function(){
....
                var dialog = BootstrapModalWrapperFactory.createModal({
                    title: '{% trans 'Extended information about the event' %}',
                    message: '<pre>'+JSON.stringify(info.event.extendedProps.description, null, 4)+'</pre>',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            label: '{% trans 'Close' %}',
                            cssClass: "btn btn-secondary",
                            action: function (button, buttonData, originalEvent) {
                                return this.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
....
</script>
```

So my main question here is such:
HOW correctly I can move ALL `<script>...</script>` blocks from html template into the external JS file?
To keep all the functionality of the django framework working! And my 1 variant was - I should use the same technique which I use for generating HTMLs with Django framework abilities. But maybe in a little shorten variant: Right inside the views.py file - CAN I somehow correctly generate on the fly full content of GLOBAL.js file which will contains ALL ... blocks from html template - where they all were previously stored.
And in a such manner - that standard django template engine can convert all {% ..... %} placeholders in a correct real content BEFORE the full content of GLOBAL.js will be generated and given out. And especially the content of translatable placeholders!!! Well, then in the HTML page template I can insert a call to a special command that can display the contents of this script at the moment the page is rendered by the browser on the client side. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'GLOBAL.js' %}"></script>
```

Am i right? If yes - how I can do that step-by-step? Or maybe there is something new and more logical way?
Django version is the latest one!!! 3.*

P.S. Also I've faced with a problem of transferring script block with content like document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){...}); Looks like such event handlers can't be moved out to the separate JS file from HTML page((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason you couldn't use Django template tags inside Javascript files (or any other filetype for that matter). As an example, here's is a view that returns rendered Javascript:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def render_javascript(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/global.js', {})
```

If you hook this view into your `urlpatterns` like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("js/global.js", render_javascript, name="globaljs"),
]
```

You can then use the `{% url %}` template tag to refer to it from your `HTML` templates like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'globaljs' %}"></script>
```

Now when your browser requests `js/global.js`, the Django view will take the template `myapp/global.js`, process it with the templating system, and return the rendered template.